# Ajax response issues

Tags: jquery

I have a script that submits data via an ajax POST. It is called from 2 different pages. On one page, the call works flawlessly and returns 200 OK with the expected response, on the other page it returns a 302 status and doesn't return any response.

These two pages use IDENTICAL code for a jQuery SmartModal window for login and the same script containing the ajax call, as well as call the same URL to post the data.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this problem?

Comment: show us the code which has error. Are u seeing any script errors in firebug console ?

Comment: Well, actually, I found out what the problem was. My ajax call is from a HTTP page going to an HTTPS page. It *SHOULD* be from HTTPS, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My ajax call is from a HTTP page going to an HTTPS page. It SHOULD be from HTTPS, too